# Overloading the << operator and printing out a double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I tried to overload the << operator to print out double pointers, but all im getting is garbage outputs. Here's my code:

```
    ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Student& s)
    {
        out << s.height << "/" << s.age;
        return out;
    }
```

What should i put in the second parameter? Right now it can print out pointers no problem, but when i changed the Student* s to Student** s it is not working.

Comment: There's no pointer at all in the code you posted. Posting the code that doesn't work is much more useful than posting code that does work and asking what the problem could be in the code you didn't post.

Comment: There are no `Student*` (to replace to `Student**`) in provided code but `Student&`...

Comment: http://www.functionx.com/cpp/examples/return2pointer.htm

Answer (score 0):

1.If you overload operator<< like this:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, Student& s)
{
    out << s.height << "/" << s.age;
    return out;
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
Student stud;
cout << stud;
```

2.If you overload operator<< like this:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, Student* s)
{
    out << s->height << "/" << s->age;
    return out;
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
Student *stud = new Student;
cout << stud;
delete stud;
```

3.If you overload operator<< like this:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, Student** s)
{
    out << (*s)->height << "/" << (*s)->age;
    return out;
}
```

use can use it like this:

```
Student *stud = new Student;
cout << &stud;
delete stud;
```

Or you can use all of this.